# What word was used in Russian for line before the borrowing of "линия"?

Tags: выбор-слова, математика

What word was used in Russian for a line before **линия** was borrowed in the 18th century?

Was it **черта**? Or something else?

Comment: I can suggest that it was `черта`, but I'm not sure. Maybe someone can check this suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В словарь древне-русского языка Срезневского есть [статья про слово *черта*](http://urokirus.com/slovarsreznevskogo/displayimage.php?pid=1901&fullsize=1):

> ЧЕРТА 1) Протяжение, имеющее одну длину без ширины и толщины, линия. *Иота едина, или едина черта не прейдет от закона. Провесть черту.* 2) *Стар.* Пограничная линия; рубеж с укреплениями. *Велели столнику и воеводе... Колычевскому быти по Белогородской черте в Олшанску.* 3) Действие, поступок. *Это прекрасная черта в его жизни. Прошедшаго житья подлейшия черты.* 4) В минералогии: царапина, сделанная на минерале твердейшим его телом. 5) У плотников: орудие, коим прочерчивают доски. 6) *Во мн.* Облик, очертание лица.

С другой стороны, у Срезневского есть и [слово линия](http://urokirus.com/slovarsreznevskogo/displayimage.php?pid=375&fullsize=1): "черта, проведенная от одной точки до другой".

Этимологический [словарь Семенова](http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Cherta-354.html):

> **Черта**
>   Древнерусское – чьрта.
>   Старославянское – чръта.
>   Общеславянское – cьrta.
>   Индоевропейское – ker(s)- (резать).
>   Слово известно с XI в., с XIV в. вошло в употребление слово «чертеж» в значении «отметка, грань». Широкое распространение слово получило в начале XVIII в. Существует во всех славянских языках, т.к. восходит к общеславянскому cьrta.
>   Родственными являются:
>   Украинское, белорусское – черта.
>   Болгарское – чьрта.
>   Производные: черточка, чертить, начертать, чертеж.

О слове линия словарь Семенова явно указывает что впервые оно упоминается в словарях с 1731 года:

> **Линия**
>   Заимствование слова произошло в XVIII в., впервые в словаре встречается в 1731 г. Современное значение слова: «черта, определяющая предел какой-либо поверхности или направление в движении».
>   Первоисточник слова – латинский язык, значение «льняная нить», «льняной шнур», «черта». В русском языке слово появилось из немецкого. Сначала в русском языке писали «линея».
>   Слово встречается в других славянских языках, при этом оно не претерпевает никаких изменений.

В то же время, церковно-славянский словарь [переводит слово черта](http://www.orthodic.org/cs/%D0%A7/3) как "1) малая часть минуты 2) малая буква". Встречается в нем и перевод слова "строка" как "линия", но это только [шестое значение](http://www.orthodic.org/cs/%D0%A1/46). Вопрос в том насколько можно пользоваться этим или подобным словарем для поиска предшественника "линии"? С другой стороны, в допетровские времена именно церковно-славянский был литературным языком.

Что касается слова **струна**, то в [словаре Стрезневского](http://urokirus.com/slovarsreznevskogo/displayimage.php?pid=1705&fullsize=1) оно упоминается только в значении "струна муз. инструмента" или "тетива". В качестве синонимов (в том числе во фразеологизмах) предлагаются "нитка", "жила", "тетива", так что струна - не претендент.

Так что **черта**, похоже является главным претендентом на предшественника слова "линия".

Comment: Is it a cognate with карта?

Answer (score 0):

There was the word "межа". Thus, the verb "отмежеваться" means 'to discard someone or something', 'to separate from somebody or something'.

Comment: But "межа" doesn't mean of "line". It is "border" (see [here](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/13/slc11311.htm?cmd=0&istext=1) and [here](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/43211/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0)).